# How to display millisecond from Date and time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

**I wish to format my date (22/03/2016 23:59:59) to string with milliseconds.**

dr.GetDateTime(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

1. `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`
2. `.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss")`

Comment: `dr.GetDateTime(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff")`

Comment: ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh':'mm':'ss.fff tt")

Comment: You don't need `':'`. Instead you need to remove the *'* so it would be `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff tt")`

Answer (score 6):

If you google DateTime.ToString(), you end up with [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) explaining this function.

Then you can find a link to [Custom Date and Time Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), which explains that to display milliseconds, you must do this :

```
dr.GetDateTime(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss fff")
```